# Python: gdal.Warp how to crate mosaic and don't save?

Tags: python, gdal

I would like create a mosaic but I don't want to save it, just have in memory or as a variable and then close. I want to do that because I would like to cut out the roof of the buildings and sometimes buildings stand on 2 raster files.

```
from osgeo import gdal

a = 'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/73776_931613_M-34-46-C-d-3-3.tif'
b = 'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/73776_933044_M-34-58-A-b-1-1.tif'

files_to_mosaic = [b, a] 

g = gdal.Warp('C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/output.tif', files_to_mosaic, format="GTiff",
              options=["COMPRESS=LZW", "TILED=YES"])
```

With the code I can make mosaic and then save it but I don't want to save that. How can I solve that?

Comment: Could you show me some example according to my code?

Comment: GDAL has also a memory driver MEM.

Comment: I need an example please.

Answer (score 0):

```
#use EMPTY '' AND FORMAT = "MEM"
from osgeo import gdal

a = 'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/73776_931613_M-34-46-C-d-3-3.tif'
b = 'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/73776_933044_M-34-58-A-b-1-1.tif'

files_to_mosaic = [b, a] 

g_MEM = gdal.Warp('', files_to_mosaic, format="MEM",
              options=["COMPRESS=LZW", "TILED=YES"])
```